# Stored Procedure is not called using php code?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin 3.1.3
In phpMyAdmin i created a procedure like this

Its created successfully .
But when i am calling it from php file no result set is returned.
Like this....

```
$conn --  server connection

$database  -- database selection
using    mysql_query ("CALL test2()");
```

following message is coming.

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wam
```

please any body give me idea !

Answer (score 0):

```
//assume there is a procedure named "verifyemail"

$uid = "11";//it can be anything.
    $proce=mysql_query(("CALL verifyemail($uid)")or die("proce_error- ".mysql_error()));
```

The warning is about the argument or arguments that should be passed while the procedure is calling. 
As in the above example, the verifyemail procudure is calling with the argument $uid.

OR

You should give the code about the procedure, in your case that should be of test2 procedure.

Hopes it'll help..!